# convert text to number with fraction in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have tried with replacing the . by , and it works. I would like to make it automatic for many values but did not work out even I tried these methods given by office
as you can see on the pic below with the method =VALUE(A2) showing nothing
[image]

[enter link description here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885)

Comment: Try Ctrl+F -> Replace ->  Findwhat: . Replace With: ,  and pres replace all. Excel should now recognize the the values as numbers

Comment: That one works as well but needed one that i rund as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`NUMBERVALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879), which allows you to specify the decimal separator.

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A2,".")
```

Since I'm used to a `.` decimal separator, I tested with `,` in the text in column A:

[image]

Comment: it worked like a charm but I have to write ; instead of , as you see: =NUMBERVALUE(A2;".")